# What does [] and [_] mean in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I believe [] means accepting the empty lists while [_] accepting a non empty list that may have anything. But then in some context such as say a function:

```
f([]).
f[_]).
f([x|y]):-dostuff.
```

Wouldn't [x|y] and [_] both be called since they essentially mean the same thing?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[_]` means "a list of exactly one element" because that's what it means in Haskell.

Comment: @melpomene, Oh if it mean just one element then things make sense

Comment: That's what it means, but not because it happens to be true in Haskell. `[]` is an empty list. Note that `[x|y]` is different than both of these. Also, since `x` and `y` start with lower case, they ate atoms, not variables. `[X|Y]` is a list of one or more elements. So a single element list will match this and match `[_]`, but a two element list will only match the former.

Comment: Prolog has *predicates* not *functions* (except when doing arithmetic expressions). They don't behave the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog one represents lists as *linked lists*. A linked list has two "patterns":

1. the empty list `[]`; and
2. the "cons" `[H|T]` with `H` and `T` parameters with `H` the *head* of the list (the first element), and `T` the tail of the list (a list with the *remaining* elements).

So we can present a list with no elements as `[]`, with one element as `[H1|[]]`, with two elements as `[H1|[H2|[]]]`, and so on.

The above notation is a bit verbose, one can use *syntactical* sugar for lists. For example `[H1, H2]` is equivalent to `[H1|[H2|[]]]`, the same way `[H1,H2|T]` is equivalent to `[H1|[H2|T]]`.

The `[_]` in your code is thus syntactical sugar for `[_|[]]`. It means that this is a *singleton list* (a list with *exactly* one element `_`), and we do not care here about that value of the list, as long as it unifies with that pattern.

> But then in some context such as say a function.

`f/1` here is *not* a function, it is a *predicate*. It here means that the predicate `f/1` is satisfied for an empty list, for a list with one element regardless what that element is, and for a list `[X|Y]` (I assume that these are uppercase identifiers, since otherwise it is only satisfied if the head is a constant `x`, and the tail is a constant `y`, which means it is not really a list).